# Swift debugging on Linux - Missing Backtrace

Tags: swift, linux

I have a crash which I am trying to locate, and even building the application as debug and executing it I don't seem to get any symbolic information.

The output I receive at the console is:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f1c51ca51c0 swift_reportError + 120
1    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f1c51cbfbe0 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalError + 62
2    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f1c51ab9be6 <unavailable> + 1186790
3    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f1c51c18ead <unavailable> + 2625197
4    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f1c51ab9be6 <unavailable> + 1186790
5    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f1c51bd4060 specialized _fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, file : StaticString, line : UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never + 96
6    myProgram                          0x000000000045909e <unavailable> + 364702
7    myProgram                          0x0000000000423f37 <unavailable> + 147255
8    libdispatch.so                     0x00007f1c5276e177 <unavailable> + 278903
9    libdispatch.so                     0x00007f1c52779edd <unavailable> + 327389
10   libdispatch.so                     0x00007f1c5277a890 <unavailable> + 329872
11   libdispatch.so                     0x00007f1c5277c5f4 <unavailable> + 337396
12   libdispatch.so                     0x00007f1c5279aa18 <unavailable> + 461336
13   libpthread.so.0                    0x00007f1c50c6f6ba <unavailable> + 30394
14   libc.so.6                          0x00007f1c4f7b9370 clone + 109
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I simply cannot find any way to expand on this information, and although I could go looking through a map file.  I feel that we have moved very much beyond that territory now with modern tooling.

Does anyone have any pointers, or indeed knows how to produce a build with more information in it.

Ubuntu 16.04, Swift 3.1.1

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: What code do you think is running at the time of the crash? Show that code so that the community help.

Comment: @MartinR, there may be some misunderstanding of what I am asking.  I am asking if there is a way to add symbolic information to the debug build to give me a stack backtrace or anything to give me something to work on.  Sadly this is not a problem which fits the demonstrable example paradigm.    If I were able to create a reproducible example then I would have been able to fix it already.

Comment: @MartinR, sadly that answer could be pretty broad, which is why I was hoping to get a backtrace to even narrow it down to a particular function or class even.  But I may have to just log every line out and work out where it stops.  I was just hoping to avoid days of work for something that swift gives me out of the box when I write the code in xcode and run it, but in production environments (linux) seems lacking.

Comment: I wonder why the stack backtrace does not provide more information. How did you compile and run the program?

Comment: I used, `swift build -c debug`.  The binary is +3mb on the release build so it is definitely different.  But sadly this looks like a long standing bug.  I am going to try upgrading to swift 4, but it doesn't look like the lldb team have looked at it.

Comment: @MartinR,  thanks for your feedback.  It's always appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

So, sadly this seems to be a bug in lldb, which uses local symbols in ELF executables, and `dladdr` cannot find them on linux platforms.

See the bug report here:
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-755

ATTENTION:

Great news though, there is a bash script which does all the work for you.  Instruction's are slight, but this is what you need to do:

Download this script:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apple/swift/master/utils/symbolicate-linux-fatal

Exectute your crashing app.

```
$ myApp &> crash.log
```

Then execute the script.

```
$ ./symbolicate-linux-fatal myApp crash.log
```

It has helped me out no end.

**Using LLDB**

You can also use the swift debugger to help if still in the development stage.

Also if you execute `lldb yourexecutable`, then `run`.  You will pause and able to fully debug your application.

Comment: I met this issue when i trying to run `swift test` on Ubuntu 16.04. Where can I found the executable that something likes `myApp`?

Comment: @Adrian_H Thanks for this question and answer. Although I wasn't able to successfully use your answer for my exact scenario, it led me to another solution (see my answer). Upvoted.

Comment: Can we run this script on Mac as well?

Comment: @Adrian_H On running command python3 `./symbolicate-linux-fatal.py appName.app` , I am getting error ldd returns with error code 1. ldd: not a regular file.

Answer (score 1):

## Enable `Core Dump`s on Linux, and use `gdb` to get a back trace.

1. Enable core dumps by modifying `/etc/security/limits.conf`

   - In that file, add the following two lines

     - `* soft core unlimited`
     - `* hard core unlimited`
2. Log out of the shell, then log back in (no restart required)
3. Double check the modification worked

   - `$ ulimit -c` should return `unlimited`
4. Run your program, when it crashes, a file name `core` will appear in the same directory
5. debug using `$ gdb <executable> <core-file>`

## Example

`$ mkdir testCore && cd testCore`

`$ touch app.swift`

```swift
// app.swift
func thisWillCrash()
{
    fatalError("crashing on purpose")
}

func wrapperFn()
{
    thisWillCrash()
}

wrapperFn()
```

`$ swiftc -g app.swift`

This will output an executable named `app`. Run it:

`$ ./app`

It will crash and now you will have a file named `core` alongside `app.swift` and `app`

Use `gdb` to get the backtrace:

`$ gdb app core`

After `gdb` starts and you get to the gdb prompt, run the `bt` command. On my Raspberry Pi 3B running Raspbian Buster, running Swift 5.1.5 this is the back trace I get:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x76d5c974 in $ss17_assertionFailure__4file4line5flagss5NeverOs12StaticStringV_SSAHSus6UInt32VtFTf4xnnnn_n () from /home/pi/swift/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so
#1  0x76aa07b8 in $ss17_assertionFailure__4file4line5flagss5NeverOs12StaticStringV_SSAHSus6UInt32VtF
    () from /home/pi/swift/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so
#2  0x004f4ab8 in $s3app13thisWillCrashyyF ()
#3  0x004f4ad0 in $s3app9wrapperFnyyF ()
#4  0x004f49c4 in main ()
```

When I do this on a real project with multiple files and using `spm` to build, the back trace includes correct file names and line numbers.

Comment: Also if you execute `lldb yourexecutable`, then `run`.  You will pause and able to fully debug your application.  This has helped me lots, assuming you are still in the dev stage and not looking to report on crashes which are on production code.  Where your answer is invaluable.